# CUDA stop working after error

Tags: cuda

After I had the following error from my CUDA program:

```
CUDA error at scan.cu:231 code=4(cudaErrorLaunchFailure) 
"cudaMemcpy(odata, g_odata,   sizeof(int) * N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)"
```

I fixed it and recompiled the program, but the program didn't proceed. It stopped at the command line prompt and I had to kill it using control+C.

After I rebooted the machine, It ran successfully.

How can I fix this without rebooting?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with CUDA 5.5 gtx550ti boost

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems where CUDA simply fails to work at all after an error, but started working again after I reload the kernel module. I have no explanation for why this happens, but I have a script that reloads the kernel module:

https://github.com/EmmetCaulfield/linux-misc/blob/master/usr/local/sbin/cuda-init

Comment: Upvoted.  I misunderstood the question.  In many cases, you won't need a script that is this complicated to accomplish this.  `sudo rmmod nvidia` by itself will unload the nvidia module.  Thereafter, any CUDA operation (as root), e.g. running `nvidia-smi -a` will automatically force a reload of the module (both of these operations require root privilege as you are showing).

Comment: Sure, but in one or two cases, I have needed a script that's this complicated and I prefer to have just one.

Comment: How to run the script? I'm new to Linux. I tried 'sudo rmmod nivida'  but it says 'ERROR: Module nvidia is in use'

Comment: I solved this problem temporarily. I switched to tty1 and restarted desktop

Comment: "module nvidia is in use" usually means you have X running.  The script by itself won't handle that case nor will simply typing `sudo rmmod nvidia`.  You would need to manually stop X so that the nvidia module becomes unused.  If you don't need X, set your machine to start up in runlevel 3 instead of 5.

Comment: @RobertCrovella is right, but in my case I use that script on my laptop, where I use the Ivy Bridge on-chip graphics, which are adequate for my needs, and use the Nvidia GPU for computation only, so I don't have an issue with the module being loaded for graphics purposes.